# stuck in microsoft report

Tags: ms-access

My report is containing some null value.

Report is generated through query

In my report I am calculating sum of every field for that I had written =iif((field name) is null,0,sum(field name))

Through this function I am getting result as 0 only if field contains some value as well

Comment: Why are you not using the footers (Group footer, Report footer) to get sums? It is the usual way. Furthermore, if data is to be modified, it is nearly always best to do it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Remou, you should be using the footers for totals. However if you wanted to carry on with the way you are doing things then try replacing the IIF with NZ(MyField,0)

Answer (score 0):

You should put that IIf statement in the query for that (or those) fields that you want to avoid nulls on. That way you can just put the Sum function in the details section of the report with impunity (assuming details section here).